# if $x = \ln{\Biggl(\tan{\Bigl( \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2} \Bigr)}\Biggr)}$ then find $\theta$ =

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Well, I was doing the problem mentioned in the title and in the below picture(Sum:-49).
I came up with an answer:- $$\theta = -i \ln{\Biggl(\tan{\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{ix}{2}\Bigr)}\Biggr)}$$
But they have given the answer Option D.
Book details:- ISBN - 9788192669557 (MCQ Mathematics).
[image: Picture from ISBN-9788192669557]

Comment: There must be a typo error in the book. Your answer is correct.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function